# While finding points of discontinuity for a composite function do I need to consider the points of discontinuity of individual functions too.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, function-and-relation-composition

I'm solving problems based on composition of functions and stuck in this problem.

> If $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, then find the points of discontinuity of $f(g(x))$.

We know that $f(x)$ is discontinuous at $\{1,2\}$ and $g(x)$ is discontinuous at $\{0\}$

$$f(g(x))=\frac{x^4}{(1-x)(1+x)(1-2x^2)}$$
which seems to be discontinuous at $\{1,-1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$.

Now while writing for the points of discontinuity for $f(g(x))$, do I need to write only $\{1,-1,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}}\}$ or do I also need to include the discontinuous points of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as we must first define $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ properly before finding $f(g(x))$.

Comment: You should also include the discontinuities of $f$ and $g$. For example: $g(0)$ doesn't exist so $f(g(0))$ shouldn't exist either.

Comment: @Randomgirl: I got your point of $g(0)$ and I also think that we should include discontinuity of $g(x)$ but how can we justify the inclusion of discontinuity of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to find the domain of $f(g(x))$. $ \\ \text{ 1) Domain of } g \text{ is all real numbers but } x=0 \\ \text{ 2) Domain of } f \text{ is all real numbers  but } x=1 \text{ or } x=2. \text{ So we need } \frac{1}{x^2} \neq 1 \text{ or } \frac{1}{x^2} \neq 2 \\ \text{ Conclusion:  Domain is all real numbers except } x=0 \text{ or } x^2 =1 \text{ or } x^2=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @Integrator So yeah you had all of them but $x=0$.

Comment: It makes great sense.